# Angular 4 and Bootstrap 4 accordion head href trigger undesired navigation

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have the following simple bootstrap accordion. This is an Angular 4 app. Currently clicking the link that should trigger the accordion toggle triggers an undesired navigation event in the browser.

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="true" href="#collapseOne" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Active Partners
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="card-block">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        Inactive Partners
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="card-block">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any insight in how to resolve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Does binding to the click event of the anchor and calling `preventDefault` suppress the change in navigation?

**Markup**

```
<a ... (click)="handleClick($event)">...</a>
```

**Component**

```
public handleClick(event: Event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

You might find it easier to use [Ng-Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) instead of Bootstrap directly.